# C#: extract last name, first name and middle name from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file that contains lots of names of people:

- ABELINDE, ELISEO JR. DELA PEÑA
- DE LA CRUZ, FRANCIA DE LA ROSA
- DE JESUS, ALMA SINOGBA
- Smith, John Paul SINOGBA
- ABORDO, EMMA DE LA TORRE
- ABORDO, JERWIN DELOS REYES
- ABAO, JARN DE LOS REYES

DELOS REYES,DE LA TORRE and DELA PEÑA are middle names.

I have no problem getting the Last name and first name middle name if it contains single value only using `split()` to put into array. I am having difficulty when the 2nd part are multiple names or has multiple surname or has suffix. How can I get these names?

Comment: Please add some sample data that you have problem with them with your expected results ;).

Comment: I don0t think you will get it solved, if the data in your file is not formatted in a way you can recognize where the middle name starts and ends it's very hard to tell.

Comment: Spanish names usually do not contain a middle name

Comment: Those are Filipino names.

Comment: What are the exact rules that *you* (as a human) use to find out where the first name ends and the middle name begins? State them clearly and unambiguously, and then we can help you translate them to code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you split by a comma ',' to get the last and first name, split the second part by space. Keep the first part as first name and the remaining as middle name.

Comment: Yes, this is my current approach, but if the person has two names like John Paul, the second name will be attached to middlename which is wrong. Also if have suffix like Sr. or Jr.

Comment: You should try to follow a fixed pattern while recording the data. It'll be easier that way.

Comment: those text file are generated by the system which is not developed by me. So I don't have access to redo the formatting of exported data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameArr = name.Split(' ');
if (nameArr.length > 3)
{
    var fName = nameArr [0];
    var lname = nameArr[nameArr.length-1];

    string middlename;
    for (int i = 1; i < nameArr.length - 1; i++)
    {
        middlename += nameArr[i];
        //probably a more elegant way of joining the names
    }
}
```

That should work?

Comment: this will work ok if the person has one lastname, one firstnam and one or more middlename. See my example list above. (f it is happen that the person has multiple names like John Paul, Paul will be included as in the minddelname.

Comment: I see. Then yes that is impossible without being able to format the data first